Problems with the openai assistant api connecting to my ionic application (node.js)
I am developing an assistant chatbot app for a company, I use ionic framework 7 and I want to use the openai assistant to connect as the chatbot of that application. I am having problems with the connection with the openai assistant and the bot's responses.when I write a prompt, the bot responds [object object];
This is the code of my server.js file
import express from "express";
import * as dotenv from "dotenv";
import cors from "cors";
import OpenAI from "openai";

dotenv.config();

const openai = new OpenAI({
    apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
    organization: process.env.OPENAI_ORG_ID,
    project: process.env.OPENAI_PROJECT_ID,
});

const assistantId = process.env.OPENAI_ASSISTANT_ID;

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

async function createThread() {
    const thread = await openai.beta.threads.create();
    return thread.id;
}

async function addMessage(threadId, prompt) {
    const response = await openai.beta.threads.messages.create(threadId, {
        role: "user",
        content: prompt.substring(0, 1000)
    });
    return response;
}

async function runAssistant(threadId) {
    const response = await openai.beta.threads.runs.create(threadId, {
        assistant_id: assistantId
    });
    return response;
}

async function getRunStatus(threadId, runId) {

    const runObject = await openai.beta.threads.runs.retrieve(threadId, runId);
    return runObject;
}

app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).send({
        message: 'Sea bienvenido a nuestro Chatbot',
    });
});

app.post("/", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const prompt = req.body.prompt;
        const threadId = await createThread();
        await addMessage(threadId, prompt);
        const runResponse = await runAssistant(threadId);
        const runId = runResponse.id;

        const pollingInterval = setInterval(async () => {
            const runStatus = await getRunStatus(threadId, runId);
            if (runStatus.status === 'completed') {
                clearInterval(pollingInterval);
                const messagesList = await openai.beta.threads.messages.list(threadId);
                const botMessage = messagesList.data.find(message => message.role === "assistant");
                const botResponse = botMessage ? botMessage.content : "Lo siento, no pude entender tu pregunta. ¿Podrías ser más específico?";
                res.status(200).send({ bot: botResponse });
            } else if (runStatus.status === 'failed' || runStatus.status === 'expired') {
                clearInterval(pollingInterval);
                res.status(500).send({ error: "Error en la ejecución del asistente." });
            }
        }, 5000);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.status(500).send({ error: error.message });
    }
});

app.listen(3000, () =>
    console.log('Server is running on port: http://localhost:3000')
);

and this is the code of my page.ts file
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { IonContent } from '@ionic/angular';
import { Message } from 'src/app/models/message.model';
import { OpenaiService } from 'src/app/services/openai.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tab4-faq',
  templateUrl: './tab4-faq.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tab4-faq.page.scss'],
})
export class Tab4FaqPage implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild(IonContent, { static: false }) content!: IonContent;

  messages: Message[] = [];

  form = new FormGroup({
    prompt: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
  });

  loading: boolean = false;

  constructor(private openAi: OpenaiService) {}


  ngOnInit() {}

  submit() {
    if (this.form.valid) {
      let prompt = this.form.value.prompt as string;

      // === MENSAJES DEL USUARIO ===
      let userMsg: Message = { sender: 'me', content: prompt };
      this.messages.push(userMsg);

      this.scrollToBottom();
      this.form.reset();
      this.form.disable();

      this.loading = true;

      this.openAi.sendQuestion(prompt).subscribe({
        next: (res: any) => {
          this.loading = false;
          let botMsg: Message = { sender: 'bot', content: res.bot };
          this.messages.push(botMsg);
          this.scrollToBottom();
          this.form.enable();
        },
        error: (error: any) => {
          console.log(error);
        },
      });
    }
  }

  scrollToBottom() {
    this.content.scrollToBottom(2000);
  }
}


So, what's the problem? Please edit the question and describe the problem.

Hello, when I write a prompt, the bot responds [object object];
